# AppsFlyerLib StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

Hi I faced next exception in logcat simetimes from AppsFlyer:

```
E/AppsFlyer_4.3.6: length=12; regionStart=0; regionLength=13
                                                    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; regionStart=0; regionLength=13
  at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:298)
  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1087)
  at com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerLib.java:272)
  at com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib.b(AppsFlyerLib.java:712)
  at com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerLib.java:39)
  at com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib$c.run(AppsFlyerLib.java:1647)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Does anyone know something about this error in logcat?
This is my initialization code:

```
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().startTracking(application, BuildConfig.APPS_FLYER_API_KEY);
```

and this one i use to track events:

```
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().trackEvent(mContext, name, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

This but was fixed on version 4.3.7. It was related to very short package names.

Comment: still happens in 4.3.8